# display sum of time in label cocoa

Tags: cocoa, core-data, sum, cocoa-bindings

I am a newbie in Cocoa and trying to learn the basic concepts. I have implanted a tableView with data(displays only time in (HH:MM:SS)) as one of the column. This value is fetched from core data. I what to display the total time in the label that is fetched from the crew data. I am using binding to display the values in the tableViewCell. I am unable to do it. Could anybody help me out as how can I do it with or without binding?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the binding, but to sum an attribute of an array of Core Data objects, you can use KVC.

```
let sum = objects.valueForKeyPath("@sum.duration") as! NSNumber
```

Comment: @sum works in the binding keypath.  It's called a KVC Collection Operator.

Comment: Will the sum change when a duration changes?

Comment: No it didn't work. :( . The problem is that it is not a number, but it is time. I want to calculate the sum of all time in the row.

Comment: @Willeke, if these were NSNumbers, yes.  Rahul - you're right, has to be an NSNumber.  Are you using NSString or NSDate?  In either case, to use `@sum`, you could create a readonly NSNumber property that `@sum` uses, and have it register duration as a dependent keypath.